# .NET collection type for storing recent list

Tags: .net, collections, queue

Is there a specific collection type in .NET that allows storing a limited number objects and removing the oldest element automatically? What's the easiest way to implement such "Recent Files" functionality?

Comment: What do you mean by "oldest" exactly? Are you talking about the object that was added last to the collection? Or do you mean the object that sorts the last according to some user-defined field? Please edit your question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try [System.Collections.Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx)?

Each time before you add an object to your Queue (`Enqueue()`), you can check the `Count` to decide if you need the oldest object to be removed (`Dequeue()`).

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a class wrapping a linked list. For a quick and dirty example for a starting point see the code below. Of course you will want to add other accessors etc. This will give you the ability to move recently accessed items to the head of the list etc.

```
public class RecentList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
  private LinkedList<T> _list = new LinkedList<T>();
  private int _maxItems;

  public RecentList(int maxItems)
  {
    _maxItems = maxItems;
  }

  public void Add(T item)
  {
    _list.AddFirst(item);
    if (_list.Count > _maxItems)
    {
      _list.RemoveLast();
    }
  }

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
    return _list.GetEnumerator();
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return _list.GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 This will work perfectly fine if you don't need random access. The alternative is to implement a queue with a fixed size which just increment head (and tail to sync.) even if it is full.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably interested in an [LRU cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754233/is-it-there-any-lru-implementation-of-idictionary) implementation, since a Queue won't give you the easy lookup ability.

EDIT: For just offering  "Recent Files" functionality LRU cache would be overkill - go with the simple Queue just like the other poster suggested.