# How to use Convert.ChangeType() when conversionType is a nullable int

Tags: c#

I mean, I want to convert this:

```
string a = 24;
Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(decimal?))
```

But it throws me an error.

UPDATE 1:

I've got a Type object where can be decimal?, int?, .. many nullable types. Then with the Type object, I need to convert the string value in type object.

Comment: Are you saying you have `Type someType = typeof(T)` and you want to use them to get a `T myT`?

Comment: You can't safely do that. Those assignments are checked at compile tim.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you expect to receive a null nullable decimal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert.ChangeType() fails on Nullable Types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531318/convert-changetype-fails-on-nullable-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this since `Nullable<T>` don't implement `IConvertable`.

You can do this although.

```
string a = 24;
decimal? aAsDecimal = (decimal)Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(decimal));
```

Might I also interest you in `TryParse`?

Comment: OK but for example, imagine that my typeConverter is a nullable type (decimal?), in Type object is there a property can get only decimal type (not decimal?) ?

Comment: can you expand your question with more details?

Answer (score 24):

See an excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531318/convert-changetype-fails-on-nullable-types):

```
public static T GetValue<T>(string value)
{
   Type t = typeof(T);
   t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) ?? t;

   return (value == null || DBNull.Value.Equals(value)) ? 
      default(T) : (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
}
```

E.g.:

```
string a = 24;
decimal? d = GetValue<decimal?>(a);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is based on Dror's answer but has slightly less overhead when dealing with null values:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(string value)
{
   if(value == null || DBNull.Value.Equals(value))
       return default(T);

   var t = typeof(T);
   return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) ?? t);
}
```

Comment: I also added a check for null or whitespace but this is a great answer thank you string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString())