# AutoMapper cannot convert enum to nullable int?

Tags: automapper

I got AutoMapperMappingException exception

> Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'DummyTypes' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, ...

when

```cs
public enum DummyTypes : int
{
    Foo = 1,
    Bar = 2
}

public class DummySource
{
    public DummyTypes Dummy { get; set; }
}

public class DummyDestination
{
    public int? Dummy { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void MapDummy()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<DummySource, DummyDestination>();
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    DummySource src = new DummySource()
    {
        Dummy = DummyTypes.Bar
    };
    Mapper.Map<DummySource, DummyDestination>(src);
}
```

Should not AutoMapper map this implicitly without any extra explicit rule?

P.S. I cannot change the definition of DummyDestination.Dummy to enum. I have to deal with such interfaces.

Comment: Would you mind filing an issue for this? https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/new - thanks!!

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/191

Comment: This was an issue and it is already fixed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like no, it won't take care of this automatically for you. Interestingly, it *will* map an `enum` to a regular `int`.

Looking at AutoMapper's source, I think the [problematic line](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/EnumMapper.cs#L63) is:

```cs
Convert.ChangeType(context.SourceValue, context.DestinationType, null);
```

Assuming `context.SourceValue = DummyTypes.Foo` and `context.DestinationType` is `int?`, you would end up with:

```cs
Convert.ChangeType(DummyTypes.Foo, typeof(int?), null)
```

which throws a similar exception:

> Invalid cast from 'UserQuery+DummyTypes' to
>   'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0

So I think really the question is why can't we cast a variable of type `enum` to `int?` [That question has already been asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3531318/497356).

This seems like a bug in AutoMapper. Anyway the workaround is to map the property manually:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<DummySource, DummyDestination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (int?)src.Dummy));
```

Answer (score -1):

Just in case if anyone want to try using a type converter

```
Mapper.CreateMap<int?, DummyTypes.Foo?>().ConvertUsing(new FooTypeConverter());

public class FooTypeConverter: TypeConverter<int?, DummyTypes.Foo?>
    {
        protected override DummyTypes.Foo? ConvertCore(int? source)
        {
            return source.HasValue ? (DummyTypes.Foo?)source.Value : null;
        }
    }
```

Cheers