# How to create map for enum in iqueryable mapping in auto mapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var emp1 = new Soure.Employee();
            emp1.TestEnum = Soure.MyEnum1.red;
            var emp2 = new Soure.Employee();
            emp2.TestEnum = Soure.MyEnum1.yellow;
            var empList = new List<Soure.Employee>() { emp1, emp2 }.AsQueryable();
            var mapExpr = Mapper.CreateMap<Soure.Employee, destination.Employee>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Soure.Department, destination.Department>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Soure.MyEnum1, destination.MyEnum2>();
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            var mappedEmp = empList.Project().To<destination.Employee>();

        }  
    }
```

I am mapping Source.Employee to Destination.Employee.
All Properties can be mapped.
But on enum mapping it gives me exception unable to map TestEnum to Int32
If i use override

```
var mapExpr = Mapper.CreateMap<Soure.Employee, destination.Employee>()
        .ForMember(x => x.TestEnum, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => (destination.MyEnum2)s.TestEnum));
```

Then it works.

Mapping classes are as bellow

```
namespace Soure
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Department dept { get; set; }

        public int age { get; set; }

        public MyEnum1 TestEnum { get; set; }

        public Employee()
        {
            this.Id = 1;
            this.Name = "Test Employee  Name";
            this.age = 10;
            this.dept = new Department();
        }
    }

    public class Department
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DeptName { get; set; }

        Employee emp { get; set; }

        public Department()
        {
            Id = 2;
            DeptName = "Test Dept";
        }
    }

    public enum MyEnum1
    {
        red,
        yellow
    }
}

namespace destination
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int age { get; set; }
        public MyEnum2 TestEnum { get; set; }

        public Department dept { get; set; }

    }

    public class Department
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DeptName { get; set; }

        Employee emp { get; set; }
    }
    public enum MyEnum2
    {
        red,
        yellow
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721466/automapper-cannot-convert-enum-to-nullable-int

Comment: Don't it possible with just using create map???

Comment: Why we need to specify more information in ForMember as If i am having different class and i create map between them it directly map it.

Answer (score 1):

The following are 2 ways of mapping enumerators using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)...

```
.ForMember(x => x.TestEnum, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => (int)s.TestEnum));
```

Another approach would be to use the [ConstructUsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192275/automapper-convertusing)

```
mapper.CreateMap<TestEnum, Soure.MyEnum1>().ConstructUsing(dto => Enumeration.FromValue<Soure.MyEnum1>((int)dto.MyEnum2));
```

Comment: he already told that, He don't want to use override i.e ForMember

Comment: Why we need to specify more information in ForMember as If i am having different class and i create map between them it directly map it.

Comment: You'd need to create a definition for those types since they are not the same.

Comment: As you can see the content of both enum are same.

Comment: if you see Mapper.CreateMap<Soure.Department, destination.Department>(); this two are also different classes. But here it won't ask for ForMember.