# Nullable problems with Activator.CreateInstance and Convert.ChangeType

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion, nullable, activator

I have a third party library which sets a given objects property using reflection as follows. (This is the simplified version)

```
public void Set(object obj, string prop, object value) {
    var propInf = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop);
    value = Convert.ChangeType(value, propInf.PropertyType);
    propInf.SetValue(obj, value, null);
}
```

And We have class with a nullable property

```
class Test
{
    public int? X { get; set; }
}
```

When I write the following code, it says it cannot convert `int` to `int?`

```
var t = new Test();
Set(t, "X", 1);
```

Since Nullable does not implement IConvertible it makes sense. Then I decided to write a method which returns the nullable version of a given value typed object.

```
public object MakeNullable(object obj) {
    if(obj == null || !obj.GetType().IsValueType)
        throw new Exception("obj must be value type!");

    return Activator.CreateInstance(
        typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(obj.GetType()), 
        new[] { obj });
}
```

I hoped to use this method as follows.

```
var t = new Test();
Set(t, "X", MakeNullable(1));
```

But it still says it cannot convert `int` to `int?`. When I debug `typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(obj.GetType())` equals `int?` but `Activator.CreateInstace` returns an `int` value not `int?`

So this is my case... Any help?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've been playing around with Activator and the like for about an hour now without any luck. It always returns the underlying type in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
public void Set(object obj, string prop, object value)
      {
          //var propInf = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop);
          //value = Convert.ChangeType(value, propInf.PropertyType);
          //propInf.SetValue(obj, value, null);
          var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop);
          if (property != null)
          {
              Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType)
                           ?? property.PropertyType;

              object safeValue = (value == null) ? null
                                                 : Convert.ChangeType(value, t);

              property.SetValue(obj, safeValue, null);
          }
      }
```

from here
[Convert.ChangeType() fails on Nullable Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531318/convert-changetype-fails-on-nullable-types)
by 
LukeH

UPDATE :
Hide base method.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EnterPoint t = new EnterPoint();
        t.BeginProcess();
    }
}

public class EnterPoint
{
    public void BeginProcess()
    {
        var t = new Test(); //Object

        try
        {
            baseDllMethod m = new baseDllMethod(); //Your DLL
            m.Set(t, "X", 1); //Problem Method, this give you error
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR EN DLL METHOD");    
        }


        xyz_D der = new xyz_D(); //Derivated method
        der.Set(t, "X", 1) ; //HIDE BASE METHOD
    }
}

public class baseDllMethod //YOUR DLL HERE
{
    public void Set(object obj, string prop, object value)
    {
        var propInf = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop);
        value = Convert.ChangeType(value, propInf.PropertyType);
        propInf.SetValue(obj, value, null);
    }
}

public class xyz_D : baseDllMethod //Inherits
{
    public new void Set(object obj, string prop, object value) //Hide base method
    {
        var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop);
        if (property != null)
        {
            Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType)
                         ?? property.PropertyType;

            object safeValue = (value == null) ? null
                                               : Convert.ChangeType(value, t);

            property.SetValue(obj, safeValue, null);
        }
    }
}

public class Test //Your Object
{
    public int? X { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: I know but Set method is in a library which I can not modify. Also, unfortunately, it is not as simple as this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static object ChangeType(object value, Type conversionType)
{
   if (conversionType.IsGenericType && conversionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
   {
       if (value == null)
           return null;
       var nullableConverter = new NullableConverter(conversionType);
       conversionType = nullableConverter.UnderlyingType;
    }
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, conversionType);
 }
```