# Generic method to return Nullable Type values

Tags: c#, nullable, generic-programming

> I wrote below method with follwing requirement -

1. input is xmlnode and attributeName
2. return the value if it is found with the associated attribute name passed
3. Where there is no value in attributeName being passed, it should return -

   3.1. For int   -1
   3.2. For Datetime DateTime.MinValue
   3.3. For String, null
   3.4. For bool, null

Below method fails for case 3.4.

```
public T AttributeValue<T>(XmlNode node, string attributeName)  
        {
            var value = new object();

            if (node.Attributes[attributeName] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Attributes[attributeName].Value))
            {
                value = node.Attributes[attributeName].Value;
            }
            else
            {

                if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
                    value = -1;
                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
                    value = DateTime.MinValue;
                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                    value = null;
                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
                    value = null;



            }
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
        }
```

When change this to

```
public System.Nullable<T> AttributeValue<T>(XmlNode node, string attributeName) where T : struct 
        {
            var value = new object();

            if (node.Attributes[attributeName] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Attributes[attributeName].Value))
            {
                value = node.Attributes[attributeName].Value;
            }
            else
            {

                if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
                    value = -1;
                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
                    value = DateTime.MinValue;
                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                    return null;
                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
                    return  null;



            }
            return (T?)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
        }
```

> It fails for string type i.e. case 3.3

Looking forward for some help.

Comment: How do you _call_ the method in your first set of code? You'd need to call it as `AttributeValue<bool?>(...)` If you just call `AttributeValue<bool>(...)` then `null` isn't a valid value for `bool`. EDIT: And your second case fails because `string` can't be used for `System.Nullable<T>` because `string` isn't a value-type struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks for a number of replies, this is what I wrote and it works for me..

It returns null for the types.

```
public T AttributeValue<T>(XmlNode node, string attributeName)
        {
            object value = null;

            if (node.Attributes[attributeName] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Attributes[attributeName].Value))
                value = node.Attributes[attributeName].Value;

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool?) && value != null)
                value = (string.Compare(value.ToString(), "1", true) == 0).ToString();

            var t = typeof(T);
            t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) ?? t;

            return (value == null) ?
                default(T) : (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
        }
```

I call it like this

```
    const string auditData = "<mydata><data><equipmentStatiticsData><userStatistics maxUsers='100' totalUsers='1' authUsers='0' pendingUsers='' adminAddedUsers='' xmlUsers='' internalDBUsers='' webUsers='' macUsers='' vpnUsers='' xUsers8021=''></userStatistics><equipmentStatistics cpuUseNow='14' cpuUse5Sec='1' cpuUse10Sec='1' cpuUse20Sec='1' ramTotal='31301632' ramUtilization ='1896448' ramBuffer='774144' ramCached='8269824' permStorageUse='24' tempStorageUse='24'></equipmentStatistics><authStatus  status='1'></authStatus></equipmentStatiticsData></data></mydata>";
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(auditData);
    var userStatsNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/mydata/data/equipmentStatiticsData/userStatistics");


    var intNullable = AttributeValue<int?>(userStatsNode, "vpnUsers");
    var nullableBoolTrue = AttributeValue<bool?>(userStatsNode, "totalUsers");
    var nullableBoolFalse = AttributeValue<bool?>(userStatsNode, "authUsers");
    var nullableString = AttributeValue<string>(userStatsNode, "authUsers");
    var pendingUsersBoolNull = AttributeValue<bool?>(userStatsNode, "pendingUsers");
    var testAttribNullableNotFoundDateTime = AttributeValue<DateTime?>(userStatsNode, "testAttrib");
    var testAttrib1NullString = AttributeValue<string>(userStatsNode, "testAttrib");
    var maxUsersNullInt = AttributeValue<int?>(userStatsNode, "maxUsers");
```

it works well for me. thanks people...

Comment: I am fine with getting null values back now. this looks like a better solution,

Answer (score 7):

For 3.4 you need to use `bool?` as the type for T, so you can return null.

Then you can use the `default` keyword for 3.3 and 3.4 (string and bool?). As per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it will return `null` for reference types and the default value for value types (like int or bool).

You can use it like

```
return default(T);
```

Comment: The requirements for the `bool` case (3.4) is that it returns `null`. This will return `false` instead and won't be distinguishable from the case where no matching attribute is found and the case where "false" is provided.

Comment: Dont you need to use it then with `bool?` as the generic argument, returning null in that case? I mean, if T is `bool` you cannot return false, so you need to use `bool?`...

Comment: just to clarify, default(T) for `bool?` will return null

Comment: Ahh, of course. Maybe just specify that in your answer. I was thinking it would be used against `bool`, not `bool?`. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your first code set using `bool?` not `bool` because `null` isn't a valid value for a non-nullable `bool`.

Your second code block fails because you can't use `string` for the generic type of `Nullable<T>` as it requires a value-type `struct` and `string` is a reference-type class.

You'll need to change your first method block to look for `typeof(bool?)` and call it with a nullable boolean type:

```
public T AttributeValue<T>(XmlNode node, string attributeName)  
{
    var value = new object();

    if (node.Attributes[attributeName] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Attributes[attributeName].Value))
    {
        value = node.Attributes[attributeName].Value;
    }
    else
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            value = -1;
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
            value = DateTime.MinValue;
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            value = null;
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool?))
            value = null;
    }

    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
}
```

Then call it as:

```
bool? value = AttributeValue<bool?>(node, "myAttributeName");
```

You also need to do a check as `Convert.ChangeType` won't work for a nullable type. A quick fix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531318/convert-changetype-fails-on-nullable-types) resolves that. (it is included in the code above)

EDIT: Here's an improved/cleaned version of your method:

```
public T AttributeValue<T>(XmlNode node, string attributeName)  
{
    if (node.Attributes[attributeName] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Attributes[attributeName].Value))
    {
        var value = node.Attributes[attributeName].Value;
        var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
    }
    else
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            return (T)(object)(-1);

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

You can add additional special cases for non-existing nodes, but all your cases except for `int` are already the default value for the types so just use `default(T)` instead.