# Returning null for generic type extension in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, extension-methods, nullreferenceexception

I have created an extension function, which takes the string as input and check for the value and based on the Generic Type, cast it to the destination type and return it, it's working well.

Now the problem is if i pass the input value as empty it should return null, for nullable types, but it simply throws exception.

For e.g.: if i want to cast it to datetime, it throws below exception:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

Below is my code:

```
public static class Extension
    {
        public static T ToNull<T>(this string value)
        {
            var stringType = "System.Nullable`1[[System.{0}, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]";

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
                stringType = string.Format(stringType, "String");
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Int32?) || typeof(T) == typeof(Int32))
                stringType = string.Format(stringType, "Int32");
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime?) || typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
                stringType = string.Format(stringType, "DateTime");
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Int64?) || typeof(T) == typeof(Int64))
                stringType = string.Format(stringType, "Int64");


            Type originalType = Type.GetType(stringType);
            var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(originalType);
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType ?? originalType);
        }
    }
```

and here how i am accessing it:

```
string s = "";
DateTime? t = s.ToNull<DateTime?>();
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

For above case i want to return null.

Comment: If you are going to use `typeof` like that, why not just write separate methods? `ToNullableDateTime` etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert.ChangeType() fails on Nullable Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531318/convert-changetype-fails-on-nullable-types)

Comment: This question is confusing

Comment: @mjwills, since i would be dealing with multiple types, i needed a common function, could you suggest a better way to handle multiple types in single function?

Comment: I wouldn't do it in a single function. I'd use multiple functions. The problem with this approach is it is impossible to know which types are supported (e.g. I can't call it with `byte?`, but that is impossible to know without delving into the details of the function itself). Multiple functions solves that issue.

Comment: @mjwills, i don't agree with you, see my answer.

Comment: My earlier comments were based on your original code not your final code.

Comment: If you passed a type argument of `String` to this method, your "calculated" type would be a nullable string... Which is not a thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then just return `default` value

```
//Check for empty or null first
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return default(T);

//Then your code
var stringType = "System.Nullable`1[[System.{0}, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer @mjwills reply about creating separate methods, i found a solution to keep it single method and still handle any types you throw to it, dynamically.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T ToNull<T>(this string value)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return default(T);
        Type originalType = typeof(T);
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(originalType);
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType ?? originalType);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Type.GetType(typeof(T).FullName)` is pointless. Just use `typeof(T)`