# Equivalent of default(T) using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, default-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Programmatic equivalent of default(Type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/c-programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype)

Is there a method or property in the Type class (or elsewhere) that I can use to find the value of default(T)?

Comment: This is a duplicate of :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/c-programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check `type.IsValueType`; if that is true use `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` - otherwise it is null.

It also helps that you can pass null to SetValue on a PropertyInfo or FieldInfo and it will work for value-types with even for int, float etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
object obj = type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
```