# How to loop through and test values of properties of already instantiated object in .NET

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

have "Googled the cr*p" out of this one so apologies if the answer is either on here, or fairly simple.

I am writing Unit tests. In this particular one I am instantiating an object using a parameterless constructor. When instantiating using that constructor none of its properties will be set.

I then, as part of the test, want to "loop" through the properties and assert that they are either "null", "0" or "false" (which would be the correct state).

I know it sounds like a dumb thing to do, but if I can do this, then I can write more efficient and readable tests for everything else.

I know I can "loop" through the properties of a "Type", but that's not an instantiated object "of type". It's a "Type" object.

In my head it should be (but obviously isn't) the following:

```
var target = new MyObject();

foreach(var property in target.GetProperties())
{
    Assert.IsNull(property);
}
```

Anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatic equivalent of default(Type)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You loop through the properties of the type, and then find the *value* of each property against an *instance* of the type:

```
var target = new MyObject();

foreach(var property in target.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
    object actual = property.GetValue(target, null);
    object expected = propertyType.IsValueType
        ? Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType)
        : null;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Easy if the class being constructed has a parameterless constructor; otherwise it's a bit harder. Also might be an idea to test against default(T) rather than null to handle value type properties. Not sure off the top of my head how to do this with a System.Type

Comment: So it was completely simple.. thanks Jon. Hopefully might be useful for somebody else coming along in the future.

Comment: this SO question >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/c-sharp-programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype< has a bit more info for handling value type properties.

Comment: @MattDavey: Have added expectations for value types (missed that before). I'm assuming that as the class under test is the one we're constructing an instance of, it doesn't matter whether or not there's a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Jon / Matt, I've done a similar thing myself - understood that "Assert.IsNull(property)" wouldn't cover everything anyway - was just using it as a quick way to show the example. Thanks again for your help.