# C# \ Dynamic \ can I check in one statement if dynamic var is null (object type) or zero (value type)

Tags: c#, dynamic, reference

Is there a support in C# 4.0 to do that in one line?

I did for objects:

```
 if (ReferenceEquals(null, myDynamicVar))
```

so now I need to see if this a zero. how to do it and is there a statement that can do both?

Comment: Why do you think a `ValueType` is always zero? `bool` for example is `false` (this is not zero). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (ReferenceEquals(null, myDynamicVar) || Equals(0, myDynamicVar)) ...
```

Comment: Thank you all - I'll use this.

Comment: You're welcome to use what you want, and this does answer your question exactly, but please bear in mind Amiram's comment when implementing.

Comment: watch out if myDynamicVar would have value of DateTime.MinValue

Answer (score 3):

```
public bool IsDefault<T>(T value)
{
    if(value == null) return true;
    return value.Equals(default(T));
}

int v = 5;
object o = null;
IsDefault(v); //False
IsDefault(0); //True
IsDefault(o); //True
IsDefault("ty"); //False
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if `o` was type dynamic, like in the question, this code would not work.

Comment: you can try to call it IsDefault<dynamic>(o) and it will work. The case is that it will return false if dynamic o = 0; That's why you shouldn't use dynamic is it is unnecessary.

Comment: the case of Tim Rogers won't work if dynamic o = DateTime.MinValue

Comment: Actually all you need to make yours work for every case is an overload `public bool IsDefault(object value)
{
 return (value == null);
}` The dynamic binder would choose the generic form except when it's null and then it would choose the object version.

Answer (score 2):

Sloppy:

```
if (ReferenceEquals(null, myDynamicVar) || myDynamicVar ==
   (myDynamicVar.GetType().IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(myDynamicVar.GetType()) : null)
{
    //Code greatness
}
```

Cleaner:

```
    public static bool IsDefault(dynamic input)
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (input.GetType().IsValueType)
        {
            return input == Activator.CreateInstance(input.GetType());
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't compile. `default` requires the type name, not `Type` instance.

Comment: That was a stupid mistake... fixed.  Thanks for pointing that out.