# Binding DefaultExpression to property in Linq-to-Entities query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I have a class that helps project entities to POCOs by emitting Linq expressions that can be used with an IQueryable.  Here is an expression I'm having some trouble with:

```
result = Expression.Bind(dProperty,
                         Expression.Coalesce(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, sProperty),
                                             Expression.Default(dType)));
```

In this statement, `dProperty` is a `PropertyInfo` representing the destination property in the binding, `dType` is the `Type` of that property, `parameterExpression` is another Linq expression representing the parameter of type `TEntity`, and `sProperty` is a `PropertyInfo` object representing the source property.

This builds, but at runtime when the Entity Framework expression visitor implementation works its way through the tree, it sees this and throws a "not supported" exception (below).  What seems to be the meaning is that the DefaultExpression I'm using as the right side of the coalescence operator expression isn't supported in EF.  I tried searching quite a bit for documentation or discussions that addressed this and couldn't find anything (of course, it's hard to do a very good search on a word like 'default').  Anyway, is it true that the C# 'default' operator is not supported in Linq-to-Entities?  If it is true, then how do I do what I'm trying to do, which is to assign a property from a `Nullable` whose generic argument type is the same as the destination property?

In other words, the linq expression would look like this if you wrote it as a lambda:

```
(/*long*/dest, /*long?*/src) => dest = src ?? default(long)
```

Here's the exception.

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unknown LINQ expression of type 'Default'.
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Nominate>b__4(Expression exp, Func`2 baseVisit)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.BasicExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Nominate>b__4(Expression exp, Func`2 baseVisit)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.BasicExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment assignment)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitBinding(MemberBinding binding)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitBindingList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression init)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Nominate>b__4(Expression exp, Func`2 baseVisit)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.BasicExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression iv)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Nominate>b__4(Expression exp, Func`2 baseVisit)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.BasicExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Nominate>b__4(Expression exp, Func`2 baseVisit)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.BasicExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression u)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Nominate>b__4(Expression exp, Func`2 baseVisit)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.BasicExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Nominate>b__4(Expression exp, Func`2 baseVisit)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.BasicExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.Nominate(Expression expression, Func`2 localCriterion)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.Funcletize(Expression expression, Func`1& recompileRequired)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter..ctor(Funcletizer funcletizer, Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.CreateExpressionConverter()
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<TakeIterator>d__3a`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at MyClass...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, LINQ-to-Entities does not support the [`Expression.Default` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.default.aspx).

However, LINQ-to-Entities *does* support the [`Expression.Constant` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338689.aspx).

If you are working with a generic type parameter, you can simply set the second parameter of the coalesce operation be a *constant*; after all, `default(T)` is going to return a constant given the same instance of `T`.

The code to do that is as follows:

```
result = Expression.Bind(dProperty, 
    Expression.Coalesce(
        Expression.Property(parameterExpression, sProperty),
        Expression.Constant(default(T), dType),
    )
);
```

I'm assuming you *aren't* working with generics, so you can't use the [`default` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) here.  However, you can [create a method that will get it for you given a `Type`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353073/50776).

(Note, if you don't want to rely on a solution based on the codification of rules *outside the code*, [you can get the result of `Expression.Default` on-the-fly with only a `Type` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12733445/50776).)

Once you have that, you can do the following:

```
result = Expression.Bind(dProperty, 
    Expression.Coalesce(
        Expression.Property(parameterExpression, sProperty),
        // Note: The example referenced was changed to an extension method
        // on Type.
        Expression.Constant(dType.GetDefault(), dType),
    )
);
```