# Can not fake guid properties using FakeO

Tags: c#, fakeo

I am trying to use the library called FakeO (https://github.com/rally25rs/FakeO)
It works fine except when there is a Guid property. Anyone have an idea what I maybe doing wrong ?

Exceptin I get is : Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Guid'.

here is the code

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Get a single instance of an object");
            var gud = Guid.NewGuid();

            var obj1 = FakeO.Create.Fake<SampleClass>(
                                                      s => s.UniqueId = FakeO.Data.Random<Guid>(),
                                                      s => s.Id = FakeO.Number.Next(),
                                                      s => s.PhoneNumber = FakeO.Phone.Number(),
                                                      s => s.SomeString = FakeO.String.Random(50));
            Console.WriteLine(obj1.ToString() + "\n");

            IEnumerable<SampleClass> obj2 = FakeO.Create.Fake<SampleClass>(10, s => s.Id = FakeO.Number.Next(),
                                                      s => s.PhoneNumber = FakeO.Phone.Number(),
                                                      s => s.SomeString = FakeO.String.Random(50));

            foreach (var obj in obj2)
                Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class SampleClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var output = "ID={0},SomeString ={1},PhoneNumber = {2}";
            return String.Format(output, Id, SomeString, PhoneNumber);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Guid` is value type, and the author did not handle unsupported `ValueType` properly. He returns 0 for all unsupported value types in the [`Data.Random`](https://github.com/rally25rs/FakeO/blob/master/FakeO/Data.cs) method, which is not quite nice for any struct type. According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype), the last lines of `Data.Random` should be fixed to

```
if(t.IsValueType)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
}
return null;
```

This will return default value for struct type, which is empty `Guid` in case of `Guid` type I believe. If you want to support `Guid` type, you can add it in `Data.Random` method just before the final check of `ValueType`:

```
if (t == typeof(Guid))
    return Guid.NewGuid();
```

I did not test my solution, but it should do.

Comment: The github page said it supported that out of the box

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be using:

```
FakeO.Distinct.Guid()
```