# DataRow column and string value comparison

Tags: c#, .net, datarow

I have the following problem. I pass values as XML like string and I'm not passing defaults such as false or 0 for numerical columns. So, I create a Dictionary where key is the column name and value is the passed value.

This is my current code

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> kvp in rowValues)
     {
        String passedValue = kvp.Value.Trim();
        String rowValue = bookingRow[kvp.Key].ToString().Trim();
        if (passedValue != rowValue)
        {
           // code here
        }
     }
```

The problem is with default values. I can see by debugging my test case that the passedValue is empty and the rowValue is 0 (the column is integer type). So, my question is - how should I re-write the code above to properly convert my passed value into the type of the column. In other words, instead of converting them both to string I need to convert passed value into correct type of DataRow column.

Sample of the passedValue - "".

Sample of the rowValue = "         " (empty string with the length of the column)

Or another example:

Sample of the passedValue = ""

Corresponding rowValue = 0 (the value is Integer in the table)

Both cases should be treated as the same value - no need to write into history.

Thanks to the answers, I am now testing this code:

```
String passedValue = kvp.Value.Trim();
        var rowValue = bookingRow[kvp.Key];
        if (Convert.ChangeType(passedValue, rowValue.GetType()) != rowValue)
        {
           String rowValueString = rowValue.ToString().Trim();
           if (rowValueString!=passedValue) // Double check to prevent cases of "" vs. "          "
              this.SaveToBookingHistory(booking_id, "M", kvp.Key, rowValueString, passedValue, ref messageText, ref statusCode);
        }
```

Comment: What is bookingRow? DataTable? If yes you can use DataColumn.DataType and the Convert.ChangeType to retrieve the original type!

Comment: bookingRow is DataRow. I can get DataType. I'm going to check Convert.ChangeType method, I was looking for that right this moment, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have all your code, so this might not be exactly correct; but you should be able to do something like this...

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> kvp in rowValues)
{
    var rowValue = bookingRow[kvp.Key];
    var passedValue = Convert.ChangeType(kvp.Value.Trim(), bookingRow[kvp.Key].GetType());
    // or, if your bookingRow comes from a table
    var passedValue = Convert.ChangeType(kvp.Value.Trim(), table.Columns[kvp.Key].DataType);
    if (passedValue.Equals(rowValue) == false)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

**Edit:** You are going to have some issues with this. You need to use the .Equals method (I've changed the code above), because ChangeType returns an object; and != does a reference comparison. This will take care of cases where the rowValue is 0 and the passedValue is 0 boxed as an object.

However, this will not address cases where you have "" and " ". Those two things are not the same, and they are not equal; and, you don't know without inspecting the values that they are strings. So, I would suggest you write some sort of functions to perform the comparisons manually.

Comment: I think it should be rowValue.DataType. I'm going to try that with this modification, thanks

Comment: This seems to work great, but I am back to my original problem with this code. The rowValue is "    " and the passed value is "" and I get them now not equal. Is there a way using the code above to keep them as the same?

Comment: Can you edit your code sample above to include some sample data. Without that, I'm just guessing as to the problem.

Comment: I added the samples. I'm adding extra check inside the if (passedValue !=rowValue) for the strings. I also added my current code I am testing now

Comment: The code is failing now because my value is "" and I need to translate it into Integer. Researching right now what can be used.

Comment: So... you want 0 and "" to be equivalent?

Comment: Yes in case of numeric type. Or empty string and null in case of date. Or empty string and false in case of boolean. In other words, I somehow need a generic Default value based on the type.

Comment: I found this method in StackOverflow 
public static T SafeConvert<T>(string s, T defaultValue)
{
 if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) )
  return defaultValue;
 return (T)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(T));
}

Comment: The problem with the method above is I need to somehow generate that default value automatically instead of passing it depending on the type. Do you have ideas as how to handle this case?

Comment: So, I am stuck with it. Can we somehow move this conversation into chat?

Comment: The problem is `kvp.Value` is of type string.  Could you make it of generic type `object` instead (in the dictionary), and whose actual type would be the same type as the bookingRow column type?  Then you would avoid converting everything to string and having these resulting issues of improper string conversion.

Comment: I may try saving it originally as an object instead of string (I can create a new similar method). Do you think that will be enough? I'm going to try that in a moment.

Comment: Turned out it was not very easy to implement this idea. Too many things depend on that Dictionary<String, String> so I need to do lots of extra work

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution in UniversalThread.com forum by Rob Jasinski. This is my final code

```
if (bookingRow.Table.Columns.Contains(kvp.Key))
        {
           String passedValue = kvp.Value;
           var columnValue = bookingRow[kvp.Key];
           Type columnType = bookingRow[kvp.Key].GetType();

           //var passedObject = Convert.ChangeType(passedValue, columnType);
           if (!passedValue.StringEquals(columnValue, columnType))
           {
              String cColumnValue = columnValue.ToString().Trim();
              if (cColumnValue != passedValue) // Double check to prevent cases of "" vs. "          "
                 this.SaveToBookingHistory(booking_id, "M", kvp.Key, cColumnValue, passedValue, ref messageText, ref statusCode);
           }
        }
```

and I also added the following StringEquals extension method:

```
/// <summary>
  /// returns default value for the passed type
  /// / See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="t"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public static object GetDefault(Type t)
  {
     if (t.IsValueType)
     {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
     }
     return null;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Compare string with object (Rob Jasinski)
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="stringValue"></param>
  /// <param name="objectValue"></param>
  /// <param name="objectType"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public static bool StringEquals(this String stringValue, object objectValue, Type objectType)
  {
     object convertedStringValue = GetDefault(objectType);
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
        convertedStringValue = Convert.ChangeType(stringValue, objectType);

     return object.Equals(convertedStringValue, objectValue);
  }
```