# Why isn't this code compiling?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

I'm writing a method to generate a DataTable taking as datasource a generic IEnumerable. I am trying to set a default value on the field if theres no value, with the code below:

```
private void createTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> MyCollection, DataTable tabela) 
        {
            Type tipo = typeof(T);

            foreach (var item in tipo.GetFields() )
            {
                tabela.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(item.Name, item.FieldType));
            }

            foreach (Pessoa recordOnEnumerable in ListaPessoa.listaPessoas)
            {
                DataRow linha = tabela.NewRow();

                foreach (FieldInfo itemField in tipo.GetFields())
                {
                    Type typeAux = itemField.GetType();

                    linha[itemField.Name] =
                        itemField.GetValue(recordOnEnumerable) ?? default(typeAux); 

                }
            }
        }
```

It's throwing this error:

> The type or namespace name 'typeAux', could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why? Shouldn't the function "Default(Type)" return a default value for that type?

Comment: `default()` requires a named type, not a `Type` reference.  For example, `default(int)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about returning null for reference types and [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) for value types

```
public static object GetDefault(Type type)
{
   if(type.IsValueType)
   {
      return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   }
   return null;
}
```

Reference: [Programmatic equivalent of default(Type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype)

Answer (score 0):

The `default` statement doesn't work with `System.Type`.

That being said, it seems more appropriate to leave that out, and use `DBNull` directly:

```
linha[itemField.Name] = itemField.GetValue(recordOnEnumerable) ?? DBNull.Value;
```

If the value is `null`, setting the result to `null` (which, in a `DataRow`, is `DBNull.Value`) seems appropriate.

Comment: but does that requirres that types like int, boolean etc be declared like Nullables?...

Comment: @WilnerAvila No - `itemField.GetValue` would only return null if the value was actually null.  Could never happen with int, bool, etc