# Why can't I pass a Type variable to the keyword "default" in c#?

Tags: c#

I was to dynamically return the default value of a type, but I can't pass the default keyword a variable of type Type.

Why not?

Eg:

```
    private object GetSpecialDefaultValue(Type theType)
    {
        if (theType == typeof (string))
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
        if (theType == typeof (int))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return default(theType);
    }
```

Gives me the compile time error:

> The type or namespace name 'theType' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatic equivalent of default(Type)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype)

Comment: Because default is resolved at compile time. Since the type you're giving it is not known at compile, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `default` does not take an instance of `Type` is that there is no `default` instruction in IL.  The syntax of default translates to `ldnull` or `initobj T` depending upon whether the type is a value type or not.

If you want to get a default value from a `Type`, perform the same logic as given [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype):

```
public static object GetDefaultValue(Type t)
{
    if (!t.IsValueType || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null)
        return null;

    return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can only use `default` with generic type parameter.

> The `default` keyword can be used in the `switch` statement or in generic code:
>
> *from [default (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25tdedf5.aspx)*

How about that one?

```
private object GetSpecialDefaultValue<T>()
{
    var theType = typeof(T);

    if (theType == typeof (string))
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
    if (theType == typeof (int))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

**Update**

You can try following instead of `default`, but **I'm not 100% sure it will work**.

```
return theType.IsValueType ? (object)(Activator.CreateInstance(theType)) : null;
```

Comment: +1. Note that `default(SomeType)` can be used anywhere, but makes not much sense in non-generic code where `null`/`new SomeValueType` can give more clarity.

Comment: I would definitely make note of Alexi's comment in your post if only for the sake of accuracy.