# how to resolve by passing type using unity container?

Tags: wcf, unity-container

I am trying to use following example provided in Microsoft site. gives compile time error while resolving by type.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323725(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323725%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

is it issue in the code, how to solve this?

```
 public class DependencyInjectionInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
{
    private readonly Type _ServiceType;

    public DependencyInjectionInstanceProvider(Type serviceType)
    {
        _ServiceType = serviceType;
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return GetInstance(instanceContext, null);
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        return DependencyFactory.Resolve(_ServiceType);  //error
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
    }
}


 public class DependencyFactory
{
    private static IUnityContainer _container;

    public static IUnityContainer Container
    {
        get
        {
            return _container;
        }
        private set
        {
            _container = value;
        }
    }

    static DependencyFactory()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        if (section != null)
        {
            section.Configure(container);
        }
        _container = container;
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        T ret = default(T);

        if (Container.IsRegistered(typeof(T)))
        {
            ret = Container.Resolve<T>();
        }

        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: with you on this one. I know the answer will be a simple one if I can just find it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long time answer, but I started Unity only in these days.
Maybe you have to call in this way:

```
  DependencyFactory.Resolve<_ServiceType>();
```

I think the problem is you are treating a Type like a parameter in the caller.
Take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650319.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The sample code has a `DependencyFactory.Resolve<T>()` but not a `DependencyFactory.Resolve(Type typeToResolve)`.

You could implement DependencyFactory.Resolve(Type typeToResolve) duplicating the example logic (refer to [Programmatic equivalent of default(Type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype) to create a default value using a Type).

The most simple resolution is to access the container member.

**Make sure to including using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;**

```
public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
{
    return DependencyFactory.Container.Resolve(_serviceType);
}
```