# C# - return default type of property type

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, system.reflection

Ok, I have a property `MyProp` like this inside `MyClass` class:

```
public string MyProp
{
   get
   {
      if (App.localSettings.Containers.ContainsKey(nameof(MyClass)) && App.localSettings.Containers[nameof(MyClass)].Values.ContainsKey(nameof(MyProp)))
         return App.localSettings.Containers[nameof(MyClass)].Values[nameof(MyProp)].ToString();

      return default(string);
   }

   private set
   {
      App.localSettings.Containers[nameof(MyClass)].Values[nameof(MyProp)].ToString();
   }
}
```

But how I can make my `return` looks like this:

```
return default(typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(nameof(MyProp)).PropertyType);
```

I'm running under Windows Runtime.

Comment: Why do you use `default` when all the types are concrete? IMHO it only makes sense if generics would be involved.

Comment: Take a look at chosen answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype

Comment: I tried `IsValueType`, but in Windows Runtime I cannot found it.

Comment: The marked duplicate has a large number of answers, including one that uses `Expressions` and which I expect would work on Winrt. If none of the discussion and answers in that other question solve your problem, please look more carefully at the Winrt runtime type system; it's significantly different from .NET's to be sure, but it mostly has the same features. I'm sure you can find a way to identify a value type in Winrt so that you can even use the `Activator.CreateInstance()` method.

Comment: If you really want help, it would also help if you would explain why in the world you want to do this. If your code example above is indicative of your actual use case, it does not seem like a useful way to write the code; if it's not indicative, please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that _is_ indicative, with a clear, precise explanation that explains what exactly you're trying to accomplish. It might be that there's a better way to address your overall problem than this particular strategy.