# Using 'Default' keyword on an instance of type 'Object'

Tags: c#, default, boxing, unboxing

When supplied with an integer (or other value type) boxed as a `object`, I'm pretty sure there is no way to use `default()` (returns the default value of a given type) on it directly to return the underlying boxed default value, is this correct?

I'd rather make a call on `object` in a single operation without having to write a load of conditionals as follows:

```
public object GetDefaultVal(object obj){
 if(obj is Guid){
  return default(Guid);
 }
 if(obj is double){
  return default(double);
 }
....
}
```

Comment: return default(typeof(obj))?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking, given that your sample won't compile due to not providing a method name, and using `Default` instead of `default`.

Comment: @Henningsson Doesn't typeof() return an instance of `Type`, which is therefore always going to be null...

Comment: Could you make the method generic instead? Or do you really need to be able to pass a boxed integer and retrieve a boxed 0 instead, for example?

Comment: @JonSkeet unfortunately not, I'm actually trying to implement `IValueConverter`

Comment: You should define a generic method and than just invoke them on any object type

Comment: Will this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/353073/580053

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can't change the method to be generic, you can just use the fact that all value types provide a parameterless constructor, so you can call `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
public object GetDefaultValue(object obj)
{
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    return type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
}
```

(The default value for all reference types is null.)