# C# Set generic property value of primitive type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to set the value of a primitive type in an generic object dynamically in C#

```
//Create a new instance of the value object (VO)
var valueObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
//Get the properties of the VO
var props = valueObject.GetType().GetProperties();
//Loop through each property of the VO
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    if (prop.GetType().IsPrimitive)
    {
         var propertyType = prop.PropertyType;
         var value = default(propertyType);
         prop.SetValue(prop, value);
    }
}
```

The problem being that I cannot use `propertyType` as a type to get the default value for. How do I get `propertyType` to a type that can be used by `default()`?

Comment: why need to set default value? Primitive has his default value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatic equivalent of default(Type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the instance to the SetValue:

```
prop.SetValue(valueObject, value);
```

If you want to set the default value, you could use:

```
var propertyType = prop.PropertyType;
var defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType);
prop.SetValue(valueObject, defaultValue);
```