# having parameters be the type of the properties of a class

Tags: c#

I have a generic method, I give it any object of type T and a list of properties and it will return the object with the properties defined by the list set to null

Here's my code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var orderDto = new OrderDto();
        orderDto.Nominal = "1";
        orderDto.OrderId = "2";
        orderDto.Type = "3";

        var clean = FieldCleaner.Clean(orderDto, "OrderId");
    }
}

public class FieldCleaner
{
    public static T Clean<T>(T dto, params string[] properties) // I want in compilation time, have autocompletion that tell user the value of properties can only be a property name of the type T
    {
        var propertyInfos = dto.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (propertyInfo.Name == property)
                {
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(dto, null);
                }
            }
        }

        return dto;
    }
}

public class OrderDto
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Nominal { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

My question is in the comment above in the code. I don't like the type string[], I want something like a **keyof T** in typescript

Im using last C# version with last .NET core

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single answerable question. For your main question, you could use an `params Expression<Func<T, TProp>>[] properties` and get the list of properties that way. Or, you know, just set the property directly.

Comment: Performance: reflection isn't really that slow - have you measured this code and found it "too slow"? You could certainly optimize that nested loop though.

Comment: You can certainly optimize speed if you simply set the properties to null “the old fashioned way”: orderDto.OrderId = null; (and you’ll have IntelliSense too). It’s not clear to me why you feel you need to do this in some method.

Comment: @HereticMonkey could you provide an example please ?

Comment: Im gonna remove my second question how performance, that's a lot less important than my question 1

Comment: You can't quite do this because not all types in c# are [Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable?view=netframework-4.7.2).  Secondly, because .net is different than javascript (by a long shot) you can do the second type, but it's literally going to be very difficult because you *have to* specify the type of each property.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/671968/215552. But @ErikPhilips provides a good warning here: you'll only be able to use this for nullable types. You could set it to its type's default value (via https://stackoverflow.com/q/325426/215552), which would be null for nullable types.

Comment: @ErikPhilips `default(T)` is a reasonable work-around.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that requires knowing the type of the property defined in the method signature.  Typescript does not require knowing the type, only that the property exists.  (Maybe I'm wrong.. I remember doing this once and I had to write out all the types before hand, I can't remember why).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn indeed, but that's quite that easy either, unless he uses the `Expression<Func<T, TProp>>` so there is a `default(TProp)` to use.  `default(T)` would give him a default instance, not a default property value.

Comment: @Erik what typescript does is not relevant to the question, and you know the type of the property via PropertyInfo.PropertyType. The linked questions demonstrate how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the following answer does what you want, there really isn't a point because it's just unnecessary.  If you have to specify the property, you might as well just set it directly.

Here is probably as close as you can get.  I don't believe you can use `params` because that would require all `TProp` to be the same type.

In visual studio when you get to the period, you'll get intellisense:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var orderDto = new OrderDto
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Name",
            CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
            CompletedOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
            Misc = Guid.NewGuid()
        };

        Console.WriteLine($"{orderDto.Id} {orderDto.Name} {orderDto.CreatedOn} {orderDto.CompletedOn} {orderDto.Misc}");

        orderDto.DefaultFor(x => x.Id, x => x.Name, x => x.CreatedOn, x => x.CompletedOn);

        Console.WriteLine($"{orderDto.Id} {orderDto.Name} {orderDto.CreatedOn} {orderDto.CompletedOn} {orderDto.Misc}");
    }
}

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static void DefaultFor<TObject, TProp1, TProp2, TProp3, TProp4>(this TObject instance, 
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProp1>> selector1, 
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProp2>> selector2,
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProp3>> selector3,
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProp4>> selector4)
        where TObject : class
    {
        DefaultFor(instance, selector1, selector2, selector3);
        DefaultFor(instance, selector4);
    }

    public static void DefaultFor<TObject, TProp1, TProp2, TProp3>(this TObject instance, 
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProp1>> selector1, 
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProp2>> selector2,
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProp3>> selector3)
        where TObject : class
    {
        DefaultFor(instance, selector1, selector2);
        DefaultFor(instance, selector3);
    }

    public static void DefaultFor<TObject, TProp1, TProp2>(this TObject instance, 
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProp1>> selector1, 
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProp2>> selector2)
        where TObject : class
    {
        DefaultFor(instance, selector1);
        DefaultFor(instance, selector2);
    }

    public static void DefaultFor<TObject, TProp>(this TObject instance, Expression<Func<TObject, TProp>> selector)
        where TObject : class
    {
        if (instance == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)selector.Body;
        var property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;

        property.SetValue(instance, default(TProp));
    }
}

public class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CompletedOn { get; set; }
    public Guid Misc { get; set; }
}
```

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EBsx8o)

Output:

> 1 Name 3/29/2019 5:14:06 AM 3/29/2019 5:44:06 AM 3800be41-7fe1-42da-ada5-4fe33ac04a84
>
> 0  1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  3800be41-7fe1-42da-ada5-4fe33ac04a84

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase a bit:

> // I want an auto-completion list in Visual Studio to tell the programmer what properties of T are available

The problem is the type `T` could be **anything**. You have to be able to use this code in a completely different assembly, where neither Visual Studio nor the compiler know about your `T` at compile time.

I won't say it's impossible. Visual Studio is very extensible, especially now we have [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roslyn_(compiler)). But that is what you'll have to do: a custom Visual Studio extension using Roslyn to analyze the code and provide the completion list. This isn't built in to the platform.

Comment: `Expression<Func<T, TProp>>` is the solution without any extensions.